# Dynamically build a table into a placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-services

I am attempting to build a table dynamically when a user hits a button. What i am trying to do is have it so that it will first build the headers of the table.

My code for trying to do this is below. So when a user hits the create table button this method is run:

```
        private void AddTableTitles()
    {
        Literal startRow = new Literal();
        startRow.Text = "<tr><th colspan=\"2\">";
        Literal Column = new Literal();
        Column.Text = "</th><th colspan=\"2\">";
        Literal endRow = new Literal();
        endRow.Text = "</th></tr>";

        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(startRow);
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(AddSiteHeader());
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Column);
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(AddMachNameHeader());
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Column);
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(AddMachTypeHeader());
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(Column);
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(AddMachModelHeader());
        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(endRow);
    }
```

NOTE: AssignPlaceHolder just puts the given item into the page. The code for that is here:

```
        public PlaceHolder AssignPlaceHolders
    {
        get { return this.AssignPlaceHolder; }
    }
```

So what i am trying to get is something like this.

> Site  |  Machine Name  |  Machine Type  |  Machine Model

as the table headers however, this is what i end up getting:

> SiteMachine NameMachine Type  |  Machine Model

Note: the "|" represents the split between columns that you should get in the table.

As you can see it will only split it up into the two columns. What exactly am i doing wrong and how can i fix this?

Note: I know i can hard code this part, but by figuring out how to get this part to work in this manner i will then be able to fix the problem i am having with the dynamic section of my table that has the amount of items fed into it determined by the amount of machines stored in the database which has the same thing happening to it as well.

**Update1**
as per request

```
        private Label AddSiteHeader()
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkBlue;
        label.Text = "Site ";
        return label;
    }
```

All those methods do is create a label and populate the text for it.

Comment: @Jame213 any reason why you are using `Literal` controls with hardcoded HTML instead of using the built in HTML objects like `HtmlTable` to build up a proper table control and then rendering the HTML from the `HtmlTable` control itself?  You probably need to show more code like what is going on in `AddSiteHeader()` which I assume just returns the text `Site`.  Also what code is getting added to start and close off your `<table>`?

Comment: @Kelsey Well i am attempting to implement this from work that the previous developer did on other pages that involve dynamic tables so there is no particular reason as to why i am using literals other than i was going off of what the previous developer has done. But if you think that using htmltable instead of literals will work better or correct then i will give it a shot.

Comment: @Jame213 I would suggest using a `Repeater` as I have shown below and just binding the `Repeater` to your list of items in whatever form it is.

Comment: @Kelsey Would a Repeater work with data upload from web services?

Comment: You can pretty much bind anything to a `Repeater`.  Even a `List<SomeObject>` would work.  I think you should look into how DataBinding works in ASP.NET because your missing some really useful functionality that might save you a ton of time in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i figured it out with using the placeholder i had previously, so i figured i would post it in case anyone else has this issue.

```
    private void AddTableTitles()
    {
        TableHeaderCell site  = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell name  = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell type  = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderCell model = new TableHeaderCell();
        TableHeaderRow  th    = new TableHeaderRow();

        site.Controls.Add(AddSiteHeader());            
        th.Controls.Add(site);
        //AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(th);

        name.Controls.Add(AddMachNameHeader());            
        th.Controls.Add(name);
        //AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(th);

        type.Controls.Add(AddMachTypeHeader());            
        th.Controls.Add(type);
        //AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(th);

        model.Controls.Add(AddMachModelHeader());            
        th.Controls.Add(model);

        AssignPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(th);
    }
```

it ended up being a simple problem which only needed to have new tablecells added for each column.

Answer (score 2):

Would a `Repeater` be more useful in this case?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="yourTable" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><%= AddSiteHeader() %></th>
                <th><%= AddMachTypeHeader() %></th>
                <th><%= AddMachModelHeader()%></th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Site") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("MachType") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("MachModel") %></td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can bind it to your datasource and save you a whole lot of work because this is doing what you are doing.  If you just need the HTML output of the `Repeater` and you want to serve the output and push it into a div or something you could pre-render it and get the HTML output using the `RenderControl` method.

Seems like how the solution is working is using the old ASP way of thinking, not ASP.NET and leveraging it's strengths.